# How to solve the error: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'decode' with django-channels

Tags: python, django-channels, channel

When I tried to execute the channels' tutorial in order to establishing the django website with websocket, the error message emerged:

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'decode'

I just executed following code:

```
$ python3 manage.py shell
>>> import channels.layers
>>> channel_layer = channels.layers.get_channel_layer()
>>> from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
>>> async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)('test_channel', {'type': 'hello'})
```

Tutorial link:
https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/part_2.html

Environment:
Ubuntu 20.04LTS with Python 3.8.10
django 4.1.3
channels 4.0.0
channels-redis 4.0.0
daphne 4.0.0
asgiref 3.5.2

I think the problem may caused by asgiref, but there is no documentation for reference.

Comment: I think `async_to_sync` requires a function input instead of a tuple. Hopefully this works. `async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)(('test_channel', {'type': 'hello'}))`

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same bug, and because I encountered [this issue](https://github.com/django/channels_redis/issues/332) I downgraded to channels_redis v 3.4.0 and the bug went away. Waiting for a nicer solution, I hope it will help.